# cannot fetch location in marshmallow after giving permission request

Tags: android

I am developing an location app which is working fine in all devices except in Marshmallow.I have requested permission during runtime and when I grant permission longitude and latitude is not fetched,if i go to settings and change the location from high accuracy to battery saving,location is fetched and the app works.I want location to be fetched at high accuracy.

```
                   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
                    Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK,
            },
            1);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

**step 1 :**- add this permission in manifiesr file

```
 android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
 android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
```

**step 2 :** ask runtime permission

```
 String permission = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.
                    checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchCityClass.this, new String[]
                        {permission}, PERMISSION_GPS_CODE);

            }
```

**step 3:**  handle permsiion result

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_GPS_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            Toast.makeText(this, location_permission_granted_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, location_permission_not_granted_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give run time permission for android 6 like this

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission already Granted
                    //Do your work here
//Perform operations here only which requires permission
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
            }
```

and if permission is not already granted override onRequestPermission Results like this

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            //Permission Granted
                            //Do your work here
//Perform operations here only which requires permission
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code your Activity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_images);

    requestLocationPermission();
    //your other codes
}

private void requestLocationPermission() {

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
   {
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    //Checking the request code of our request
     //If permission is granted
    if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Displaying a toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted now you can get the location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
            //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            Toast.makeText(this, "Oops you just denied the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
}
```

Add this on your Mainfest XML

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```