# Android Intent image picker from gallary... Why can't show in some devices.?

Tags: java, android

Why choose a picture from the gallery by >>Intent<< > can't show in some devices. I'm Thai ,Sorry for my language ...Thank U

```
public void click(View v){
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "select??"), 1);
}
```

---

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK&&requestCode == 1) {

                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(get_Path(data.getData()));

    //--I use This >>uri<<  for setImage ....But cant't show in some devices.?


        }
}
```

---

```
public String get_Path(Uri uri) {
        String path = ""; ///////////////
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor == null) {
                path = uri.getPath();
            } else {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int num = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                path = cursor.getString(num);
                cursor.close();
            }

        return  path;
    }
```

Comment: On which devices doesn't it show?

Comment: huawei p10 Android 7 - problem
Asus Android 6 - problem
Google Nexas 6 API 25  - problem 

But Samsung galaxy Android 4 - No Problem

Comment: you need to include runtime permissions to access those data (on android >= 6.0)

Comment: Thank U ... So musch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning in Android 6.0 or >7 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.
[read about this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

and follow this link of my ans my question [how to ask runtime permssion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512639/cannot-fetch-location-in-marshmallow-after-giving-permission-request/44512710#44512710)

Comment: Thank U ... So musch :)