# How to ask permission (RunTime) again if the user deny for the first time

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I want to re ask the permission to the user in the situation if he/she deny for the first time. I have set the permission but my app runs even if I press **deny** option. I have a code which should do the things which I want to do but I get Cant resolve symbol **Snackbar** when I hit Alt+Enter it created another activity and remaining **-make** and **-permision_available_camera** gets red error.

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
            @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            // BEGIN_INCLUDE(permission_result)
            // Received permission result for camera permission.
            Log.i(TAG, "Received response for Camera permission request.");

            // Check if the only required permission has been granted
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Camera permission has been granted, preview can be displayed
                Log.i(TAG, "CAMERA permission has now been granted. Showing preview.");
                Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permision_available_camera,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "CAMERA permission was NOT granted.");
                Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permissions_not_granted,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
```

Comment: follow this link [rathod nilesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512639/cannot-fetch-location-in-marshmallow-after-giving-permission-request/44512710#44512710) it will help you

Comment: nope. I have done that.. if the user deny it will show permission needed but the app runs despite the permission was denied. But I want to pop up again Allow or Deny permission and the app should run only when the user allows otherwise disfunction in the case of deny

Comment: than you can handle permission result in onRequestPermissionsResult() method

Comment: I don't think you should ask permission again if the user denies, all you can do is, don't take the app forward , just show them a toast or a dialog telling them that this permission is required for the app to work correctly and ask them to grant permission in the settings. (May be take them to settings when they click ok on the dialog?)

Answer (score 10):

@Arjun Thakun Here is a way to manage the concept of ask permission again and deal with all the ways the user can answer when the app asks about permissions

```
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //.... write file into storage ...
            System.out.println("SDK > BuildVersion TRUE");
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 666);  // Comment 26
            System.out.println("go to requestPermissions");
        }
    }
    onLoad();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 666: // Allowed was selected so Permission granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                Snackbar s = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),"Permission Granted",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                View snackbarView = s.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                textView.setTextSize(18);
                textView.setMaxLines(6);
                s.show();

                // do your work here

            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && !shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[0])) {
                // User selected the Never Ask Again Option Change settings in app settings manually
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Change Permissions in Settings");
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage("" +
                                "\nClick SETTINGS to Manually Set\n"+"Permissions to use Database Storage")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);     // Comment 3.
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            } else {
                    // User selected Deny Dialog to EXIT App ==> OR <== RETRY to have a second chance to Allow Permissions
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Second Chance");
                    alertDialogBuilder
                            .setMessage("Click RETRY to Set Permissions to Allow\n\n"+"Click EXIT to the Close App")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("RETRY", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Integer.parseInt(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
                                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("EXIT", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    finish();
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }};
```

Comment: My app already having `WRITE_SMS` permission `OPPO F5   7.1.1`  but again it  automatically its asking for `write to sms records/logs permission` if i deny not able to receive sms on device old apk `targetsdk was 23` updated app with new `targetsdkversion 27` getting issue .not on fresh install

Answer (score 2):

> Try this

Basically here we are trying to read the content from the External Storage. For that, we have to ask the user for runtime permission. If the user allows it's fine, but if the user denies the permission it will display a second dialog/message box until the user accepts the permission

1. Asking for permission

[image]

2. If the user denies it will display the 'Permission Needed' dialog whenever the user launches the application

[image]

3. If the user presses the OK button it will ask permission again.

[image]

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public static int REQUEST_PERMISSION=1;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            permission_fn();


        }

        private  void requestStoragePermission()
        {
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("Permission is needed to access files from your device...")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_PERMISSION);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).create().show();
            }
            else
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_PERMISSION);
            }
        }

        private void permission_fn()
        {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_PERMISSION);
                }
            }
            else {

                requestStoragePermission();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,  int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION) {

                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Thanks for enabling the permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //do something permission is allowed here....

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow the Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }

        }


        }
```

> Add user permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: OK. Understood it